# How to denote a sequence in terms of a set and a function?

Tags: sequences-and-series, elementary-set-theory, notation

Let $s=(a,b,c)$ be a sequence. This sequence can be expressed as a tuple $(S,f)$, where $S=\{a,b,c\}$, $f:\{1,2,3\} \rightarrow S$, and $f$ is a bijective function. In fact, $f(1)=a$, $f(2)=b$, and $f(3)=c$.

My question is, what is the appropriate notation for denoting that $(a,b,c)$ and $(S,f)$ are representations of the same object?

Is it correct to use the equal sign? $(S,f)=(a,b,c)$?

Or should I use the equivalence sign? $(S,f)\equiv (a,b,c)$?

Or is there a more suitable sign?

I appreciate any help you can provide.

Comment: Neither notation is correct. If $s$ is actually a sequence and ot a tuple defined as $\langle\langle a,b\rangle,c\rangle$ or the like, then in fact $s=f$ if you index your sequences by the positive integers.

Comment: Mathematicians usually reserve "sequence" for functions indexed by the natural numbers. $(a,b,c)$ would be a list. If you [edit] the question to tell us why you need a name for the equivalence of two list representations we might be able to help.

Answer (score 0):

There is no "the" appropriate notation. The use of mathematical notations depends very much on context and the conventions of targeted mathematical audience.

There are two ways to denote a (real) "sequence" of length $n$, which are essentially the same:

- an element of $n$-fold Cartesian product $\mathbb{R}^n$,
- an element of the set $\mathbb{R}^{\{1,2,\cdots,n\}}$, i.e., a function $f:\{1,2,\cdots,n\}\to\mathbb{R}$

Similarly, if you are talking about a set $S=\{a,b,c\}$, the triple $(a,b,c)$ can be thought as

- an element in $S^3$,
- an element of the set $S^{\{1,2,3\}}$, i.e., a function $f:\{1,2,3\}\to S$